# Django cannot find ajax static file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Im using Python and Django. I have tried to implement a simple ajax call, however the function never gets called.

- I am assuming that the static js file cannot be located and hence the event is never triggered.
- There is no log error either
- Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry folder structure pic does not want to upload but basically

```
sProduct\
  myapp\
  sproduct\
  manage.py
  static\
   js\
     jquery-3.2.1.min.js
     myapp-ajax.js
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2exl1&c-4p9g2(8!h)si1g7ilvidk&31fg%@nlkp)^32k1d28g'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

#LOGGING_CONFIG = None
#LOGGING = {"INFO"}
#import logging.config
#logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Application definition

ENVIRONMENT = "dev"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'markdown_deux',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_tables2_simplefilter',
]
```

index.html (base file)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/myapp-ajax.js">
</script>
```

myapp-ajax.js

```
$('#qty_id').change(function(){
    var catid;
    qid = $(this).attr("data-quoteid");
    $.get('/calcTotalPrice/', {quote_id: "2"}, function(data){
               $('#total').html(data);
    });
});

$('#price_id').change(function(){
    var catid;
    qid = $(this).attr("data-quoteid");
    $.get('/calcTotalPrice/', {quote_id: "2"}, function(data){
               $('#total').html(data);
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def calcTotalPrice(request):
    print "Test"
    tot = 9
    return HttpResponse(tot)
```

Log Output

```
[23/May/2017 19:51:48] "GET /quote/search/quoteSearch HTTP/1.1" 200 5701
[23/May/2017 19:51:48] "GET /static/jquery-3.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1771
[23/May/2017 19:51:48] "GET /static/myapp/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1759
[23/May/2017 19:51:48] "GET /static/myapp-ajax.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1753
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the js in your path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/js/myapp-ajax.js"></script>
```

but you could just use the static template tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/myapp-ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: @Shillz your welcome if you would like to mark as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `static/` folder needs to be inside your app folder. So it looks like you created an app called `myapp/`, so your folder should look something like:

```
myapp/
  static/
    -- static files here --
  views.py
  models.py
```

You can also try putting a `console.log("test");` in your JS file. If the file is being loaded in correctly, you should see that in your console.